# Remove variable in string PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a string like this:

```
$mystring = "some words1 some more words2 <script>some variable inside</script> some more words3";
```

I want to remove script tags and inside it.
I want to have "some words1 some more words2 some more words3" 
How can I remove that part

Comment: *"Remove variable in string"* - Remove what variable? The title and question are unclear. There are no variables here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
$srting = 'some words1 some more words2 <script>some variable inside</script> some more words3';

echo strip_tags_content($srting);

function strip_tags_content($text) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
 }
```

// Only For script tags

```
preg_replace('(<script>(.*?)</script>)', '', $text);
```

// output :some words1 some more words2 some more words3

Comment: How can we edit this function to remove just between <script> </script> I have some other <div> 's in string. It remove all

Comment: updated my answer :)